# Add a label to the top left corner of tikz plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I am starting with the "pgfplots" package to make "tikzpicture". I have two problems.
I would like to add a label (A) to the top left corner of tikz plot, like this figure :

[image]

I tried this :

```
\node[above right, inner sep=0pt] at (fit.north west) {above right};
\node[left] at (-0.2, 1.5) {(A)};
```

And It doesn't do what I want!

This is my assumption :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[ 
    legend style={at={((2.2, 0.75)},anchor=north east, at={(axis description cs:2.2, 0.75)}},
    xlabel={X TITLE},
    ylabel={Y TITLE},
    title={GRAPH TITLE},
    align =center,
    xmin=0,xmax=5,
    ymin=0,ymax=1.01,
    xtick pos=bottom,
    ytick pos=left
  ] 
%   \node[below left] at (axis description cs:1,1) {A};
    \addplot+[no markers, dotted, line width=2pt,color=red,%
         domain=0.01:4.9, samples=9,
         ->] {exp(-(1/1.5)*x)};
    \addlegendentry{REF 1}
    \addplot+[no markers,  thick,line width=2pt,color=red,%
         domain=0.01:4.9, samples=9, mark=none,
         ->] {exp(-(1/2)*x)};
    \addlegendentry{REF 2}
    \addplot+[no markers, dashed, line width=2pt,color=blue,%
         domain=0.01:4.9, samples=9,
         ->] {exp(-(1/3.5)*x)};
    \addlegendentry{REF 3}
    \addplot+[no markers, thick, line width=2pt,color=blue,%
         domain=0.01:4.9, samples=9, mark=none,
         ->] {exp(-(1/4)*x)};
    \addlegendentry{REF 4}
    
    \node[above right, inner sep=0pt] at (fit.north west) {above right};
    \node[left] at (-0.2, 1.5) {(A)};
    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My second problem is that I get curves with arrows:

[image]

**Is there any way to remove them, in order to have a simple curve without arrows or marks?**

Comment: You have explicitly added the arrow tips with the `->` option that's used on all the `\addplot`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with the arrows is easily solved: You add them yourself with `->`, just remove this and the arrow heads disappear.

The second issue is slightly(!) more complicated:
You need to set `clip=false` and you can then position a label using the `rel axis cs:`, i.e. the relative axis coordinate system (from 0 at your `xmin` and `ymin` to 1 at your `xmax` and `ymax`. However, you can give this node coordinates outside the range from 0 to 1, which will them appear outside the graph area.

Here is an example of how you might achieve this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{axis}[ 
        legend style={at={((2.2, 0.75)},anchor=west, at={(rel axis cs:1.1, 0.5)}},
        xlabel={X TITLE},
        ylabel={Y TITLE},
        title={GRAPH TITLE},
        xmin=0,xmax=5,
        ymin=0,ymax=1.01,
        xtick pos=bottom,
        ytick pos=left,
        legend entries= {Ref 1, Ref 2, Ref 3, Ref 4},
        clip=false
        ] 
        \node[anchor=south east,font=\bfseries\Large\sffamily] at (rel axis cs:-0.1,1) {A};
        \addplot+[no markers, dotted, line width=2pt,color=red,%
        domain=0.01:4.9, samples=9] {exp(-(1/1.5)*x)};
        \addplot+[no markers,  thick,line width=2pt,color=red,domain=0.01:4.9, samples=9, mark=none] {exp(-(1/2)*x)};
        \addplot+[no markers, dashed, line width=2pt,color=blue,%
        domain=0.01:4.9, samples=9] {exp(-(1/3.5)*x)};
        \addplot+[no markers, thick, line width=2pt,color=blue,%
        domain=0.01:4.9, samples=9, mark=none] {exp(-(1/4)*x)};     
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd suggest `clip mode=individual` instead of `clip=false`. The difference is that then plots will still be clipped if they extend beyond the axis (e.g. if the domain extended to 7), but the node is not clipped.  (Another strategy might be to add `name=foo` to the axis options, and `\node at (foo.outer north west) {A};` after `\end{axis}`.)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `clip mode` option. This, indeed, sounds more like the desired effect.

Answer (score 5):

If you name the axis, then you can access the axis anchors outside the axis environment (no clipping).

I also moved the legend, although it's not clear exactly where you wanted it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[ 
    legend style={at={(rel axis cs: 1.2, 0.75)},anchor=north west},
    xlabel={X TITLE},
    ylabel={Y TITLE},
    title={GRAPH TITLE},
    align =center,
    xmin=0,xmax=5,
    ymin=0,ymax=1.01,
    xtick pos=bottom,
    ytick pos=left,
    name=border
  ] 
%   \node[below left] at (axis description cs:1,1) {A};
    \addplot+[no markers, dotted, line width=2pt,color=red,%
         domain=0.01:4.9, samples=9,
         ] {exp(-(1/1.5)*x)};
    \addlegendentry{REF 1}
    \addplot+[no markers,  thick,line width=2pt,color=red,%
         domain=0.01:4.9, samples=9, mark=none,
         ] {exp(-(1/2)*x)};
    \addlegendentry{REF 2}
    \addplot+[no markers, dashed, line width=2pt,color=blue,%
         domain=0.01:4.9, samples=9,
         ] {exp(-(1/3.5)*x)};
    \addlegendentry{REF 3}
    \addplot+[no markers, thick, line width=2pt,color=blue,%
         domain=0.01:4.9, samples=9, mark=none,
         ] {exp(-(1/4)*x)};
    \addlegendentry{REF 4}

  \end{axis}

  \path (border.north west) ++(-0.2, 3pt) node[above left]{(A)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]